# Object property not changing

Tags: javascript

I have this code :

```
var olddata = req.body;
    var saveimage = '';
    if (req.files.headerImage) {
      var fileuploaded = req.files.headerImage;
      lib1n618.saveUploadedFile(fileuploaded, '/home/', '', false, function(err, filename) {
        saveimage = filename;
      });
    } else {
      saveimage = rows[0].datas.headerImage;
    }
    Object.assign(olddata, { headerImage: saveimage});
```

The problem is that the value `headerImage` of the `olddata` object does not change, even though the `saveimage` variable is set correctly to the newly uploaded image url.
I've tried `olddata.headerImage = saveimage` but does not work either.

Comment: `lib1n618.saveUploadedFile` is asynchronous you cannot set `saveimage` inside the callback and expect to access it outside the callback

Comment: `saveUploadedFile` is an async process. Your assign is getting called before its callback is fired. As this is node you could use [`util.promisify`](http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html) to use the promise interface/async-await for that code.

Answer (score 0):

`lib1n618.saveUploadedFile` is a **[callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks)**, and callbacks are executed after its containing method.

`Object.assign(olddata, { headerImage: saveimage});` is executed before `saveimage = filename` in the `saveUploadedFile` callback, thus olddata will never be set to the right value.

```
var olddata = req.body;
    var saveimage = '';
    if (req.files.headerImage) {
      var fileuploaded = req.files.headerImage;
      lib1n618.saveUploadedFile(fileuploaded, '/home/', '', false, function(err, filename) {
        // 2. runs after Object.assign
        saveimage = filename;
      });
    } else {
      saveimage = rows[0].datas.headerImage;
    }
    // 1. runs first: 
    Object.assign(olddata, { headerImage: saveimage});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use an async process, you cannot get the results in the next line, except if you have used the `await`. You should wait somehow until you have them available. One simple solution could be to add a promise.

```
var olddata = req.body;
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var saveimage = '';
    if (req.files.headerImage) {
        var fileuploaded = req.files.headerImage;
        // This is an async process
        lib1n618.saveUploadedFile(fileuploaded, '/home/', '', false, function (err, filename) {
            saveimage = filename;
            resolve(saveimage);
        });
    } else {
        // This is sync
        saveimage = rows[0].datas.headerImage;
        resolve(saveimage);
    }
}).then(function (saveimage) {
    // Now you have the data
    Object.assign(olddata, { headerImage: saveimage });
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just one last question, I'm using `axios` to call this point, should use async/await to get the results? `axios.post('/api/v1/homepage', formData, {
                            headers: {
                              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                            }
                        }).then(function (response) {
                          console.log(response);
                        })
                          .catch(function (error) {
                          console.log(error);
                        });`

Comment: You are most welcome! You don't have to change it, the `async` is a new and clean way to get the results of an async process, e.g in the next line. If you would like, read and learn about it, is good to use it instead of the old structures, but you can live without it.